# Add img to HTML File Type download of React component

Tags: html, css, reactjs, image, download

Here is a simplified version of my React component:

```
export class SomePage extends Component {

  const downloadAsHTML = () => {
  const element = document.createElement("a");

  const domNodeToSave = document.getElementById("second-child-div");
  const modifiedDomNodeToSave = domNodeToSave.cloneNode(true);
  modifiedDomNodeToSave.style.margin = "10px"; // example modificaiton

  const htmlSnippet = modifiedDomNodeToSave.outerHTML;

  const styleSheets = document.styleSheets;

  let allStyles = "";

  for (let i = 0; i < styleSheets.length; i++) {
    const styleSheet = styleSheets[i];

    const rules = styleSheet.cssRules;

    for (let j = 0; j < rules.length; j++) {
      const rule = rules[j];
      allStyles += rule.cssText + "\n";
    }
   }

  const styleBlock = `<style>${allStyles}</style>`;
  htmlSnippet += styleBlock;

  const file = new Blob([htmlSnippet], {
   type: "text/html",
  });

  element.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  element.download = "file.html";
  document.body.appendChild(element);
  element.click();
};

  render () {
    return (
      <>
        <div className="first-child-div">Stuff here</div>
        <div id="second-child-div" onClick={()=>this.downloadAsHTML()}>
           <span className="some-other-styling-here">
              <h1> Title </h1>
              <p> Paragraph </p>
              <img src="../some/relative/path/image.jpg"></img> // LINE IN QUESTION
              More things here
           </span>
           More html elements, nested styling, and text here
        </div>
      </>
    )
  }

}
```

When the user clicks on `second-child-div` and the `div` gets downloaded as an `.html` file (with all the styling retained), I want the downloaded `.html` file to include the `img` indicated in the "LINE IN QUESTION". Currently, the image is displayed on the UI, but is NOT displayed in the `.html` downloaded page.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export class SomePage extends Component {

  downloadAsHTML = () => {
    const element = document.createElement("a");

    const domNodeToSave = document.getElementById("second-child-div");
    const modifiedDomNodeToSave = domNodeToSave.cloneNode(true);
    modifiedDomNodeToSave.style.margin = "10px"; // example modification

    const imgElement = modifiedDomNodeToSave.querySelector("img");
    if (imgElement) {
      const imgSrc = imgElement.getAttribute("src");
      fetch(imgSrc)
        .then(response => response.blob())
        .then(blob => {
          const reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onload = () => {
            imgElement.src = reader.result;
            this.createAndDownloadFile(modifiedDomNodeToSave.outerHTML);
          };
          reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
        });
    } else {
      this.createAndDownloadFile(modifiedDomNodeToSave.outerHTML);
    }
  };

  createAndDownloadFile = (htmlContent) => {
    const styleSheets = document.styleSheets;
    let allStyles = "";

    for (let i = 0; i < styleSheets.length; i++) {
      const styleSheet = styleSheets[i];
      const rules = styleSheet.cssRules;

      for (let j = 0; j < rules.length; j++) {
        const rule = rules[j];
        allStyles += rule.cssText + "\n";
      }
    }

    const styleBlock = `<style>${allStyles}</style>`;
    htmlContent += styleBlock;

    const file = new Blob([htmlContent], {
      type: "text/html",
    });

    const element = document.createElement("a");
    element.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    element.download = "file.html";
    document.body.appendChild(element);
    element.click();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <div className="first-child-div">Stuff here</div>
        <div id="second-child-div" onClick={this.downloadAsHTML}>
          <span className="some-other-styling-here">
            <h1> Title </h1>
            <p> Paragraph </p>
            <img src="../some/relative/path/image.jpg" alt="Image"></img>
            More things here
          </span>
          More html elements, nested styling, and text here
        </div>
      </>
    )
  }
}
```

> This code fetches the image, converts it to a Base64 data URL, and
> then updates the  element's src attribute with the data URL. This
> way, the image will be included directly in the downloaded HTML
> content, ensuring it displays correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I just tried this and I'm still getting "could not load image"

Comment: This code is working on my machine. Please check Syntex properly.                               Every things is inpossible until is done

Comment: Nevermind, it seems to work now. Guess I needed a refresh. Thank you so much!